# nvm management node version

Tags: pm2, nvm

I used the nvm management node version, installed two versions, one is 6.10.1, one is 7.7.4, but in koa2 project, nvm use 7,  use pm2 open cluster mode, can not start normally. Pm2 logs error: /root/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.1/bin/node: bad option: --harmony-async-await. However, I am in the pm2 process file defined in the "interpreter": "/ root / .nvm / versions / node / v7.7.4 / bin / node", why not I specified the version of the node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't specify node (interpreter) versions when running pm2 in cluster mode. Try it without cluster mode.

@see https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/issues/1034